# What will be the max length of base64encode string of length 10 in python?

Tags: python-2.7

What max length can I expect to a base64encoded string of length 10 in python?
I need to specify that in my database.

Comment: 16 bytes, always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every base64 character encodes 6 bits. If your original string is 80 bits (10 * 8), 80/6 = ~13.3 so you need 14 characters to represent all 80 bits, plus two padding characters.

base64 string must have a multiple of 4, as every 4 characters maps to 3 bytes. The '=' character is used as padding.

EDIT: for clarity, 14+2 = 16

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression to check if a string is base64 encoded or not:

^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$
In base64 encoding, the character set is [A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and + /]. If the rest length is less than 4, the string is padded with '=' characters.

^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})* means the string starts with 0 or more base64 groups.

([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$ means the string ends in one of three forms: [A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}, [A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}= or [A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==.